# Запятая после «следовательно»

Tags: запятые, союзы, вводные-слова

Правда, что можно либо так:

> Ананас — полезный фрукт, следовательно тебе надо его есть, сынишка.

либо вот так?

> Ананас — полезный фрукт — следовательно, тебе надо его есть, сынишка.

Comment: К отвечающим. Никого не смущает искусственность такого предложения? Что это за канцелярское (официальное, книжное, научное) "следовательно" в обращении к сынишке? Ну какая мама, да и папа, скажет так?! Разве что сыну, маменькину сыночку...

Comment: Ну... Тут теоретически может быть иронический подтекст. Маленькая, хрупкая мама пичкает крупного, пухлого сына ананасами (говорят, они способствуют похудению). В любом возрасте и виде ребенок для матери все равно сынок, сыночек, сынуля... Из опыта: моя бабушка как-то учила мою старшую сестру жизни (Л., ты ничего не понимаешь! Вот доживешь до моего возраста...); та не выдержала и сказала: "Бабуль, имей совесть, я сама уже дважды бабушка..."

Comment: Да уж, ешь ананасы, рябчиков жуй...  Конечно, не нужно изучать грамматику на таких предложениях про ананасы.  В этих случаях я отвлекаюсь от конкретного содержания (лексического наполнения) и вижу только грамматическую форму. По этой форме и дан ответ, художественность текста про ананасы лучше бы не обсуждать. И  вот опять бесконечный разговор про вводное слово СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО, превратившееся в наречие (с благословления Грамоты).   Устает (как?) следовательно. Именно такое содержание мне видится в нем.  А в тексте про ананасы книжному словечку уж точно не место.

Comment: А в принципе у нас много тем, которые можно было бы обсудить на Мете (о правильных вопросах и ответах, об общем уровне форума, о комментариях и т.д.)  Да только туда никто не ходит, и обсуждать, конечно же, не будут.

Comment: @Sharon Это та же петрушка, что и со "значит" (здесь Грамота как раз "хорошо себя ведёт"). Только **не в наречие, а в союз**, и не с благословления Грамоты, а по словарям, в том числе Ефремовой, где значение союза даже на первом месте. Не ***как** устал*, а *поэтому, вследствие этого, в силу этого устал*. // Но я не защищаю отсутствие запятой, мне больше нравится лояльность Грамоты в вопросе о "значит", где говорят о сближении союза с вводным словом и более частотным его обособлением.

Comment: Ничего,  они когда-нибудь и здесь исправятся.  Наречию, которое как бы союз, здесь не место.  Вы на него посмотрите внимательно.  Оно в простых предложениях может использоваться? Как образовалось? От глагола следовать, ведь наречия следовательный нет. Служебная форма изначально, причем в качестве вводного слова. Устает (как?) следовательно.

Comment: Какое опять наречие, при чём тут это? О наречии нигде речи нет. И снова туда же: *устает (как?) следовательно*. // *Поэтому устает*.

Comment: Это наречие на О по своей форме, которое "притворяется" союзом  и которое было создано для того, чтобы быть вводным словом в простых предложениях. Когда его поместили в сложное предложение, оно стало претендовать на союз, но в нормальной (не школьной) грамматике союзом его считать отказались (там официальный союз ТАК ЧТО.  Вот такая история...  Везде борьба, даже среди слов. Может, они тоже одушевленные.

Comment: Сюжет на тему ананасов (о художественной разговорной речи):  – Мама, а ананасы – полезный фрукт?– Да, сыночек.  – А почему тогда наш кот их не ест?  (Надо будет в рекламу отправить, может возьмут.)

Comment: @Sharon А словари фиксируют школьную грамматику?

Comment: Толковые словари? У них свои правила, как я думаю. Возможно, с семантическим уклоном. Ну это надо у "словаристов" спрашивать. Я по вузовской грамматике даю материал,  а там написано: грамматическая лексема в значении союза, дополнительный структурный элемент для выражения отношений между частями предложения в СПП.  Но в любом случае вводное слово может обозначить такие отношения, оставаясь вводным словом.  Я не вижу разницы между ЗНАЧИТ и СЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО.

Comment: @Sharon  Я тоже не вижу.

Comment: А почему  знаки разные?

Comment: Не разные. При союзе "значит" тоже, говорят, не надо запятую, но пока ещё чаще ставят в силу вводности и "привычки". Как вы говорите: "Ничего, они когда-нибудь и здесь исправятся".  :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что без запятой после "следовательно" можно обойтись.

Например, в таком контексте (чем-то похожем на [эпизод](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rO4NNMlpCcM) из фильма "Белое солнце пустыни". *Опять ты мне эту икру поставила! Не могу я ее каждый день, проклятую, есть!*):

— Опять ананасы?! Мама, я на них уже смотреть не могу!
— Ананас — полезный фрукт, следовательно [= поэтому] тебе *надо* его есть, сынишка.

[следовательно](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)
**II. *союз.*** (присоединяет члены предложения и предложения со значением следствия). Поэтому, вследствие этого, значит. *Отец много работает, **следовательно** очень устаёт. Свет горит, **следовательно** родители ещё не спят.*

*Но бывает и так, когда люди тонут вдалеке от спасательных постов, **следовательно всем нужно** знать способы оказания медицинской помощи* (М. Лавренова. Книжная полка спортсмена-подводника).

P. S. Вариант с двумя тире (как вставка) — точно "не можно".

Answer (score 1):

Правильно:

***Ананас полЕзный фрукт** — // **следовательно,** / тебе надо его Есть, / сынИшка.*

БСП, второе предложение является **следствием** первого. **Тире** как основной знак.

Первое тире не ставим, там **нет паузы**.

Постановка знаков соответствует интонационной схеме.

Comment: Риммы вариант тоже верен. Просто разная интонация.

Comment: Не ведитесь на интонацию, сэр! Интонацию надо освоить на практике, а это не так просто. Римма за Грамоту, где велят не обособлять вводное слово, потом что оно как бы союз. Самозваный это союз, если вы разберетесь в теме на достаточно высоком уровне. А пока слушайтесь Грамоту.  Если любите слушаться, а не думать.

Comment: И у Розенталя про это правило, и в РАН написано. Как не слушаться, мэм?

Comment: Я сегодня просматривала тексты в Нацкорпусе, а там многие не слушаются. Вот что с этими писателями делать!  РАН свои правила будто не для них пишет.